# Delete key doesn't work in vim on iTerm2

Tags: keyboard, terminal, iterm

Firstly, I typed some thing on insert mode, like

```
Hello
```

At this stage, if I didn't exit from insert mode, <kbd>delete</kbd> works and can delete the whole word if I want.

If I quit insert mode, and open insert mode again, this `Hello` can't be removed by <kbd>delete</kbd>. But the newly typed in content can be removed.

I've renamed my .vimrc, problem still exits.

And I did some test on remote server through iterm, didn't encounter the same issue.

What could be the cause of this problem? How to fix it?

Comment: With 'delete' you mean backspace? Removing whole words in insert mode can be done with `Ctrl-W`, try that. If that does nothing, there's something wrong with your vim. I use iTerm 2 and have never had such problems.

Comment: Yes, I can use `dw` or `dw`+`shift` in normal mode to delete words. But `backspace` and `ctrl` + `w` both don't work in the second situation I mentioned above.

Comment: But you can use backspace on the normal command line outside vim? Very weird.

Comment: @oarfish, yes, I can, and in remote server vim I don't have such problem, all just happens in a sudden. I can't get the clue for now.

Comment: What vim version do you have? I have vim 7.4.481, and I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a feature of vim, although IIRC it wouldn't be enabled by default.

`backspace` is a setting in vim, and you can set three different parameters: `indent`, `eol`, and `start`

If you run `:help backspace`, it will tell you:

```
Influences the working of `<BS>`, `<Del>`, `CTRL-W` and `CTRL-U` in Insert
mode.  This is a list of items, separated by commas.  Each item allows
a way to backspace over something:

value     effect
indent    allow backspacing over autoindent
eol       allow backspacing over line breaks (join lines)
start     allow backspacing over the start of insert; CTRL-W and CTRL-U
          stop once at the start of insert.
```

The one that isn't set for you is `start`.

If you add `set backspace=indent,eol,start` to your .vimrc, you'll be able to backspace over anything in insert mode.

Comment: "feature"... For some reason, I'm seeing it enabled by default on a fresh macOS 10.13 with a brew install of vim latest.  This solution still resolves the issue.

Answer (score 33):

I also had this, the natural text processing default values were wrong for me.

- MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)
- 10.14.3 (Mojave)
- Iterm2 3.2.7

Go to `Preferences > Profiles > Keys` and load the default preset `Natural Text Editing` and delete all entries that are about `delete` and `delete` behaviour. After that it works as expected.

Comment: Same, except I just removed the entries about "Del->", but did not add a "Sends ^H" binding. Then it worked as expected.

Comment: @DagW confirmed, the ^H binding is unnecessary.

Comment: Had to dig too deep into wrong posts just to find this as the right answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: I had the issue on my Tmux and Iterm2 for long time, I never find a solution until I found your post here.

Comment: Yes! this is about iterm configuration, not vim itself.

Comment: Will there be any other side effects of removing these delete entries?

Comment: Ive yet to have any issues with it.

Comment: FYI I also have `Natural Text Editing` enabled, and only had to remove the mapping for `Del->0x4`

Comment: Man, you saved me.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, after trying all the possible solution found on internet, it was just that the option `Delete key sends ^H` was not selected.

So make sure that this option **is selected** here : `iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Keys`

Comment: its below the "presets" drop down on the bottom, but does not help for vim on MBP 2021 Monterey

Comment: "was not selected": do you mean you had to add it or remove it to make it work?